# Dynamic cast an object to a specific class to use a function

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Here is a piece of java code, and let's assume `org.abc.Test` is an interface.

```
for (Object obj : objectArray[]) {
    if (obj instanceof org.abc.Test) {
        ((org.abc.Test)obj).someMethod();
    }
}
```

Now suppose class `org.abc.Test` is passed dynamically as a `String`, the code may be like this:

```
String className = "org.abc.Test";
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
for ( Object obj : objectArray[]) {
    if (clazz.inInstance(obj)) {
        obj = clazz.cast(obj);
        obj.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the statement `obj.someMethod();` can't pass compilation, because the compiler doesn't know the specific class of the object after casting.

So I think some statement like this should be used:

```
Class<? extends org.abc.Test> clazz;
```

Can somebody help fix this? I'm just new to java reflection mechanism.

---

BTW, I found `obj = clazz.cast(obj);` is not the right way...

Comment: Would                 (org.abc.Test) obj.someMethod();    work?

Comment: Which version of java are you using?

Comment: @peggy yes, that is sure.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I'm using java 1.7 and eclipse, the compilation wont pass, but when debugging using some method the compiler dont know is ok, i mean, add a watch variable `obj.someMethod()`

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work because `obj` is still only an `Object` to the compiler, even after `obj = clazz.cast(obj);`. You need an explicit cast as @Peggy mentioned: `((org.abc.Test)obj).someMethod();`

If you want to make this truly dynamic, you can do the following:

```
if (clazz.isInstance(obj)) {
    clazz.getMethod("someMethod").invoke(obj);
}
```

You don't even need to cast in this case.

Comment: yes, I'll learn to use `Method.invoke()`. Reflection feels quite good. thks

Answer (score 3):

Since `forName()` returns a `Class<?>`, you would have to perform an unchecked cast to `Class<? extends Test>`. With that in place, your code works (with a few minor corrections):

```
String className = "org.abc.Test";
Class<? extends Test> clazz = (Class<? extends Test>) Class.forName(className);
for ( Object obj : objectArray) {
    if (clazz.isInstance(obj)) {
        clazz.cast(obj).someMethod();
    }
}
```

As @epoch points out in the comments, you can also get rid of the cast by using `asSubclass()`:

```
Class<? extends Test> clazz = Class.forName(className).asSubclass(Test.class);
```

Comment: you could prevent the unchecked cast by using `isAssignableFrom`, or using `asSubclass`

Comment: @Keppil This should works. suppose the className being `org.springframework.ui.Model`, and I don't want to use `import`, so the Class cast  statement will become `Class<? extends org.springframework.ui.Model> clazz = Class.forName(className).asSubclass(org.springframework.ui.Model.class);`, which is not so brief. The reason why dont want `import` is that, If I know the exact Class, I could simple use the first solution instead. Thanks all the same :)